# Create elevation-service from GeoTIFF using Python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, vrt

I'd like to create a little server for us, that tells us the elevation of a point in a GeoTIFF file. I already got it working basically using the following:

```
dataset = gdal.Open('test_file.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
px, py = convertLatLngToPixels(geotransform, lat, lng)
val = self.dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(px, py, 1, 1)
```

Now the issues is, that our real raster file, is a VRT that combines several GeoTIFFs. Using my code now on that VRT does not work any more...

Does anybody know any solution to using a VRT file?

Comment: Study the source code of https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html#gdallocationinfo or use that as is.

Comment: But I'd need it for python... But i guess i could use the result of the `lifonly` option and then continue inside my code?
But the issue will be that `gdallocationinfo -lifonly` is not really fast...
Is there a fast way to find the file that I'd need to use inside python?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work anymore"? Throws an error? Gives the wrong value? ... I don't see why it wouldn't work on a vrt as opposed to a tif.

Comment: Borrow code from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdallocationinfo.py#L246 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in comments, you can find the answer in [gdallocationinfo sources](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/9f1bfb89aacd6b991ac5ab91bdfe011bc5794e9a/gdal/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp#L386-L388). It does the following thing:

```
In [37]: band = ds.GetRasterBand(i)

In [38]: band.GetMetadataItem('Pixel_1000_1000', 'LocationInfo')                                                                                                                                               
Out[38]: '<LocationInfo><File>/files/Files/GIS/raster_nsk/test.tif</File></LocationInfo>'

In [39]: band.GetMetadataItem('Pixel_992644_2000', 'LocationInfo')                                                                                                                                             
Out[39]: '<LocationInfo><File>/files/Files/GIS/raster_nsk/abc1.tif</File><File>/files/Files/GIS/raster_nsk/abc2.tif</File></LocationInfo>'
```

Comment: The questioner wants pixel values, your answer seems to show something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find an answer for your question here: [Profile Tool has too high resource consumption: Alternative or work around?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343027/profile-tool-has-too-high-resource-consumption-alternative-or-work-around/347698#347698)

In my solution I'm using a VRT file that combines ~5000 8MB TIF files to a virtual DEM mosaic for building a terrain profile, and I'm really impressed about the processing speed of Python GDAL.